# Binary fortran file crashes under Make

Tags: makefile, fortran

I have a binary that runs under my default shell.

The binary runs perfectly o.k. with:

```
./binary input.dat
```

However, if I put this inside a make file:

```
 SHELL=/bin/bash

 runos:
      ./binary input.dat
```

The code crashes and leaves me quite helpless.
Here is what I tested so far, everything inside my Make file and in the shell:

1. `ulimit -a`: identical.
2. Set the shell to bash as seen above.
3. diff of the environment variables in SHELL and Make with:

   `env | sort > vars.1`

   inside make

   `env | sort > vars.2`

   Then run the binary with the extra variables in Make with the following command:

   `env SHLVL=2 MAKELEVEL=1 MAKEFLAGS= ./binary input.dat`
4. strace in the shell and inside make:

   `strace -o debug binary input.dat`

The code keeps on crashing in Make, and runs in the shell. I am already thinking to dump Make for my test cases and just write shell scripts. But I am curious to know what is the difference.

The Fortran code (a mix of F77, F90 and F95) was compiled with gfortran-4.4 and the following options:

```
FFLAGS= -g -fbacktrace
```

So, the concrete question is, what can I do to make this binary run under make in Debian!?

#### update:

I just tested again in a CentOS machine (v5.8), The code inside Makefile does not crash (GNU Make version 3.81).
I also tested on my Debian Wheezy and openSUSE 11.4, both with GNU Make version 3.82 - It crashes!
I tested on Debian Squeeze with GNU Make version 3.81, and it does crash. So, I think it is not dependent on the GNU Make version.

#### error when crashing:

```
 enter timeloop
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 timestep:     1  time: 2.500E-02 days         delt: 2.500E-02 days        
 -------------------------------------------
    terminated in routine react_snia      
    maximum number of iterations exceeded   
    bye now ...                             
 -------------------------------------------
failure in timeloop
no further time step reduction possible
try reducing min. time step, bye now ...
```

#### trying to work around 'GNU Make' using 'waf'

It has been a while since I wanted to test [waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/), so here is another interesting observation:
I wrote a `wscript` which contains a function:

```
import os

def run(ctx):
    os.system('./binary input.dat')
```

And `waf run` runs!

If I changed the `run` method to:

```
import subprocess as sp
def run(ctx):
    sp.call('./binary input.dat', shell=True)
```

The binary also *works* as expected.

So, now I am thinking `GNU Make` forks a new sub-shell in a way that causes may binary to fail (although, under RHEL 5.8 Make did work).

Comment: No error message when the code crashes?

Comment: @eriktous, I do have error messages from the code, but I don't think they are relevant. The code crashes when exceeding a number of Iterations in the solver. This number is defined inside the file input.dat

Comment: If I understand this correctly it doesn't really 'crash' in the traditional sense of the word, but the program terminates gracefully after recognizing there is no convergence. Is this right? So the real question is why there is convergence when started from the shell, and not when started by make.

Comment: @eriktous, yes you are right. I have some more insights ... see above.

Comment: I think you are barking up the wrong tree. Start looking for a bug in your code instead of blaming make.  The code would only care about its shell/environment if it is using DLLs or explicitly acessing environment variables via getenv(), getarg() etc.  Are you reading from stdin?  If none of the above then start looking for an array access out of bounds or something similar that causes a change in behavior depending on how memory gets allocated at runtime.

Comment: @george, thanks but Fortran is really primitive it does not even have `getenv(), getarg()` in this code... And I am sure there is some problem with the code, but right now I need some testing utilities that work with the old code (I am refactoring it rewriting it in C).

Comment: those are non-standard but common extensions.. anyway have you tried calling your binary from a shell script and letting make call the script?  One curios thing i found messing around is make uses the shell specified by SHELL= in the makefile but passes the SHELL variable from the calling shell to the process. Wierd but I cant see why that would cause an error.

Comment: @george, yes I did. You also see I defined shell to be /bin/bash, because I suspected an error with dash or so. This also happend with make-v.3.81 from vanilla sources in RHEL5.8 and CentOS 5.8. The patched version of CentOS\RHEL does not contain this bug ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### solution: compile make from sources ...

Read to find out more.

OK, so after being pretty much desperate, I did what I simply should have done before blame `make` for  all my troubles.
I thought the problem is Debian specific. But I am guessing the version in CentOS-5.8 is a patched version, although it says it's v.3.81.
So, for those who wonder my solution was:

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/make-3.82.tar.gz
tar xvzf make-3.82.tar.gz
cd make-3.82
./configure
./build.sh
 # copy make to the directory with the binary and input and run the local make version
./make
# everything works as expected !!!
```

I thought let's narrow it down -

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/make-3.80.tar.gz
tar xvzf make-3.80.tar.gz
cd make-3.80
./configure
./build.sh
 # copy make to the directory with the binary and input and run the local make version
./make
# everything works as expected !!!
```

Is it the version 3.81 ?

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/make-3.81.tar.gz
tar xvzf make-3.81.tar.gz
cd make-3.81
./configure
./build.sh
 # copy make to the directory with the binary and input and run the local make version
./make
# FAIL! Like with the make version in Debian.
```

Hence, I think I bumped into some very weird bug in GNU Make v.3.81.